# Interface with method that has interface{} parameter not working

Tags: go

I'm trying to implement some interfaces in Go.

I have InterfaceA:

```
type InterfaceA interface{
    read(interface{}) string
}
```

I then have InterfaceB:

```
type InterfaceB interface{
    fetch()
}
```

I have a function:

```
func Read(a InterfaceA) {}
```

I have StructA, which satisfies InterfaceA via it's methods, but instead of having a variable "interface{}", it is passed InterfaceB as such:

```
type StructA struct {}

func (a *StructA) read(b InterfaceB) string {
    resp := b.fetch()
    return resp
}
```

This seems to work for my unit tests, but when I import the package I get an error stating that InterfaceA is not implemented correctly, because it is expecting "read(interface{})" not "read(InterfaceB)". Error:

```
StructA does not implement InterfaceA (wrong type for read method)
have read(InterfaceB) string
want read(interface {}) string
```

The reason I'm trying to pass an interface to the read() function is so that I can mock out the "i.fetch()" method, but still test the rest of the read() function.

I also can't pass the read method of StructA an interface parameter (e.g. `read(b interface{})`, because then `b` won't have the `fetch()` method.

Am I doing this wrong? I thought that this was working as my unit tests work. I've only encountered the issue when importing the package.

Comment: You can define `InterfaceA`'s method `read` as taking an argument of type `InterfaceB` instead of `interface{}`. Although if you're planning to have these types in different package you'll have to export the methods.

Comment: `read(interface{}) string`!= `read(b InterfaceB) string`. The types should really match, interface{} in an interface is not a generics wildcard to be replaced at random. Set it up so that the types match

Comment: `read(queuehelp.InterfaceB)` != `read(interface{})`, functions types are invariant., See the FAQ: https://golang.org/doc/faq#covariant_types

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the comments. I've managed to get this to work via type type assertions. More details can be found here: golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions